# Exclude controller from route with string param .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, system.web.routing

I want to have an endpoint that looks like: localhost:5000/abc123

This is basically to replicate the functionality of tinyurl.

Controller

```
[HttpGet("/{myString}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string myString)
{}
```

This works but all files now come through this contoller eg: localhost:5000/runtime.js etc

Is this possible to do only for certain strings?

Comment: Is there a pattern for URLs that are supposed to match `[HttpGet("/{myString}")]` ? E.g. 3 letters + 3 numbers like in your question.

Comment: Why not put the files into folders under wwwroot?The default wwwroot will have css,js,lib folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-constraint-reference) to filter values for `myString`

For example, if a file name is a string containing a dot `.` is a valid suggestion in your case, you can use the following `regex` to accept alphanumeric strings

```
[HttpGet("/{myString::regex(^\\w+$)}")]
```